# Searching for a user's questions with [tag] highlights the tagword

Tags: bug, search, tag-search, highlighting, user-search

When searching for a user's questions with [tag], the tagword gets highlighted / bolded in the post's paraphrase for some reason.
This should only be happening when searching the word in general.

[image: highlighting of the 'rules' tagword]

In addition to being unnecessary, it is also inconsistent. Below, the word `football` is not highlighted in the tag description.

[image: 'football' is not highlighted in the tag description]

---

This does **not** happen when searching for the [tag] itself, only when the `user:#` parameter is specified.

Comment: This happens when using *any* additional parameter beyond [tag]. For example, `[bug] isaccepted:yes`, `[bug] hello`, `[bug] score:2`, etc. all will highlight "bug" in search results.